# Finding the Lipschitz constant of a function from it's graph

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I have a function graph and I want to find it's Lipschitz constant; I don't know the closed form expression of the function. Can anyone suggest any method? It does not matter if it is a bit conservative. [image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: When is your slope maximized? |f(x)-f(y)|< c |x-y| implies |(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)| < c so c is the bound of the derivative if your function is smooth

Comment: @IrbidMath, so I should find the maximum slope?

Comment: I would take the slope of the lines this seems like lines combined together it is not smooth but still lipschitz if the rate of change is bounded

Comment: @IrbidMath thank you. So I calculate the slope of any line joining A = (x_0,y_0,z_0), and B = (x_1,y_1,z_1) where these tuples A, B are from the slanted part of the graph? What would be the best choice of A, B then?

Comment: I would take two points from the blue part (after the slide it grows again steep growth ) since I guess that where I can find the maximum